# Are newer SLX chainrings compatible with older series?

Tags: chainring

I have an SLX FC-M660 chainset which has worn out chainrings. I'm looking to replace them but I don't know if they are compatible with newer FC-M7000 series.

Answer (score 4):

No, zero compatibility. Generally speaking any 104/64 10-speed Shimano chainrings should be fine to replace the rings on FC-M660.

Comment: I checked that but couldn't find a circular 32T chainring. They have oval shapes.

Comment: @Ender a currently available one that should work well is Y1DS98010

Comment: that one is a currently made middle 32 that's compatible with a bunch of 9 and 10 speed 104/64 cranks

Comment: It's a Deore FC-M510 chainring. Isn't it a lower quality part comparing to SLX group? I don't understand why Shimano do not offer SLX compatible parts anymore. My next drivetrain will definetely be SRAM.

Comment: @Ender: The FC-M660 comes in two sizes: 44-32-22T / 48-36-26T. If your bike has the second size, you can still find XT replacement in the Trekking range (FC-T8000).

Comment: @Ender you could look at it that way, but otoh the deore chainrings for 104 have good performance and wear life for cheap. They're steel, but the weight penalty is small and they tend to work well for people that are wearing out 104 rings in the first place.